# How run task asynchronously whith Celery in Django App?

Tags: python, django, celery

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'FBIsystem',
    'mathfilters',
    #'background_task',
    'celery',
    'widget_tweaks',
)

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = 'False'
```

my celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celery_try.settings')

from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_try',
             backend='amqp',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

i have a view:

```
def home(request):
    try:
        return render(request, 'app/home.html')
    finally:
        print '1'
        mytask.delay()
```

and I have a script:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task()
def mytask():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Test 1234!")
```

Actually it render home.html after 10 seconds and then print Test 1234!
My goal is render home.html and AFTER 10 seconds run mytask()

Any solution?

Comment: i have CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = 'False'

Comment: Same result if you try to remove the quotation mark around it?  `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`. Hmm - should be disabled by default anyways

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: Depending on your version it might be `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`

Comment: same result with CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False, but i think it is False by default.
It wait 10 seconds, print test 1234! and at the end render page:
I need that it render page and only after wait and print. Please, help

Comment: What happens if you call mytask.delay before you `return render(request, 'app/home.html')`?

Comment: @RaideR same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to call asynchronously (as you already do) `mytask` right before you return the rendered HTML. Something like:

```
def home(request):
    mytask.apply_async()  # delay() is just apply_async() with *args and *kwargs
    return render(request, 'app/home.html')
```

Comment: I tried, but nothing is happening.
I tried to remove time.sleep(10) in script and not print the same...

Comment: whit CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True it run script, but if is False nothig happen

Comment: That can happen only if you have no workers running, or all the available workers were busy.

Comment: how can i test if worker is running? Celery has default broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', right?

Comment: Execute something like `celery -A <your application module> status` . You should see at least one worker running. If not, run one.

Comment: there is an error: Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.

Comment: That means you have no workers running, as I suspected.